# Python: Expected type 'socket.pyi', got 'socket' instead

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm updating an old Python project that I did not create. My IDE (PyCharm) is marking the argument `socket` in the `Transport()` constructor as erroneous.

```
import socket

import paramiko

# Open a transport for SFTP
host = "my.sftp.com"
port = 22
my_socket = socket.socket()
my_socket.bind((host, port))
transport = paramiko.Transport(my_socket). # Error occurs here
```

At the indicated line, PyCharm highlights the word `socket`, and gives this error:

```
Expected type 'socket.pyi', got 'socket' instead
```

How can I resolve this error? I tried adding `from socket import pyi`, but the `socket` library has no member called `pyi`. Googling turned up nothing.

I'd appreciate any guidance here.

Comment: You named your variable `socket`, just as the module name.

Comment: If you change your variable name `my_socket = socket.socket()` the problem should go away. I don't have a good handle on .pyi files, but they are generated by tools to hold type hints for interfaces. Somewhere along the line PyCharm confuses your variable with the like-named module. Best not to mix module names and variable names.

Comment: @Frodon @tdelaney Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the error remains the same even after renaming the variable from `socket` to `my_socket`. I've updated my example code.

Comment: `socket.pyi` sounds like the name of a type stub file, not a type. It sounds like someone tried to add type hints for paramiko and screwed it up.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica Hm. That's possible. It might also be that PyCharm is just be getting confused, because the authors of `paramiko` overloaded the constructor of the `Transport` class with 3 types: `str`, `Tuple[str, int]`, or `socket`. Regardless of which I use, PyCharm highlights it with an `Expected type 'socket.pyi', got X instead.` error.

Comment: I see a similar problem with `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM); sbuf = boltons.socketutils.BufferedSocket(s)` - for some reason PyCharm thinks that the type of `BufferedSocket.__init__(sock)` is "socket.pyi", yet this is not actually mentioned in the boltons' source code. I haven't found a workaround yet...